# Open a form based on data from a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an app that searches through customer information on a *SQL Server* database.

There are three forms:

1. The first allows the user to lookup info based on several different criteria, like Account no, Last name Phone Number, etc.
2. The second form correctly displays the information from the first form.

I want to open a third form based on a value in the result set on the second form, a field called `Master_ID`.

I have created a Global variable that stores the contents of the `Master_ID` field on the second form when the `Master_ID` field is clicked.

Then I want to execute the on click event on a button that contains the following code:

```
Private Sub tranHisBtn_Click()



    Dim transferSQL As String

    transferSQL = "SELECT dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID, dbo_Master_Accounts.FirstName, dbo_Master_Accounts.LastName, dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],""hh:nn:ss ampm"") AS TranTime, dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku, dbo_Transaction_Table.Description, Right([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Description],6) AS tranAccnt, [dbo_Transaction_Table]![ArAmt]*-1 AS Amnt, dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID " & vbCrLf
    transferSQL = transferSQL + "FROM dbo_Master_Accounts INNER JOIN dbo_Transaction_Table ON dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID = dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number " & vbCrLf
    transferSQL = transferSQL + "WHERE (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Description) Like ""%Transfer To%"") AND ((dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID)=" & Chr$(34) & GBL_Master_Id & Chr$(34) & ")) " & vbCrLf
    transferSQL = transferSQL + "ORDER BY dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],""hh:nn:ss ampm"");"

    Dim trancon As ADODB.Connection
    Set trancon = CurrentProject.Connection
    Dim tranRs As New ADODB.Recordset
    tranRs.ActiveConnection = trancon
    tranRs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    tranRs.Open transferSQL

    'DoCmd.OpenForm "TransferbyNumFM" ', , , "Master_Id = 'transRs.fields(0)'"

    MsgBox "good"

End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to set the record source for the third form.  Everything runs perfectly until I try to open the third form.

Comment: I can't help it, but this sounds like bad design. What is the use case for your app, i.e. what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I guess the question remains, how do you open a form based on a data field in a recordset.  e.g. tranRs.fields(0).value  .   The design is proper for its  use.  I just need answer to the stated question.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, open the form with DoCmd, pass the MasterID as OpenArgs, set the recordsource of the Form object in the OnOpen Event of the 3rd form to the SQL you have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The problem I have is that the query is created in VBA and has a variable in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The problem I have is that the query is created in VBA and has a variable in the where clause.  ((dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID)=" & Chr$(34) & GBL_Master_Id & Chr$(34).  That variable is filled from a global variable that gets filled by clicking on The Master_ID field in form 2.  So, I don't know how to reference the query as a record source in the 3rd form since it's not in the query list. all the data is there except I can't get it into the recordsource.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can set Form.RecordSource = transferSQL, you don't need a query object, just the SQL as string. As a default for the form you can set WHERE 1=2

Comment: In the last form  in the data tab the recordsource = transSQL which is in the query list . I have the following in a button that opens the form:

Comment: i Have the recordsource property in the form set to  transferSQL, which is in the list of queries. In the button that open the form I have  DoCmd.OpenForm "TransferbyNumFm", _
         Form.RecordSource = transferSQL, _
         wherecondition:="Master_ID=" & (GBL_Master_Id) which gives me a syntax error about parantheses. Close but no cigar

Comment: It's not what I suggested

Comment: Roland, can we move this to chat? I am in unexplored territory and need a compass. I have the SQL in in the on_click of the button, and open it as a record set, is that correct? And I will set the recordsource property of the form to blank. Is that correct as well?

Answer (score 1):

As I said: Open the form with DoCmd and set the recordsource of the Form object in the OnOpen Event of the 3rd form to the SQL *string* you have. No need to create a recordset, either. And never try to pass a recordsource as a filter in a `DoCmd.OpenForm`

Oh, and my error: since you have a global variable (i.e. a public variable declared in a module) you don't even need to pass it as an OpenArgs, you can simply do the following on Button Click

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "TransferbyNumFm"
```

and then, in the class module of Form3 do

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim transferSQL As String

    transferSQL = _
        "SELECT dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID, " & _
            "dbo_Master_Accounts.FirstName, " & _
            "dbo_Master_Accounts.LastName, " & _
            "dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction, " & _
            "Format([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Time_of_Transaction],'hh:nn:ss ampm') AS TranTime, " & _
            "dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku, dbo_Transaction_Table.Description, " & _
            "Right([dbo_Transaction_Table]![Description],6) AS tranAccnt, " & _
            "[dbo_Transaction_Table]![ArAmt]*-1 AS Amnt " & _
        "FROM dbo_Master_Accounts " & _
            "INNER JOIN dbo_Transaction_Table ON dbo_Master_Accounts.Master_ID = dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number " & _
        "WHERE(((dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku) Like '%Transfer%')) " & _
        "ORDER BY dbo_Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction"

    Me.RecordSource = transferSQL

End Sub
```

The Recordsource of Form3 can be unassigned before this point, though you will need it to add fields (but you can remove it later on)

Comment: First, Thanks for spending so much time. I have never worked with class modules before, so I am reading.  With the 3rd form open in design mode I created a class module.  Hope thats right. And I don't understand what you mean By "The Recordsource of Form3 can be unassigned before this point, though you will need it to add fields (but you can remove it later on)" Do I set that by accessing the recordsource property of the form?    But Thanks again Roland, really appreciate it.

Comment: I mean the module of Form3, maybe calling them class modules was irritating. And what I mean with unassigned: a form can have a recordsource or not. Since you are assigning it by VBA the form can be unbound to start with. Please read up on how to write code for access forms.

Comment: I am reading, but what do you mean by the module of form 3? When I get this sorted out, wish I could email you a beer. Thanks again

Comment: Got it working! Last move was to put the query string into the on_open event of the third form and Viola. Thanks again Roland.

Comment: Nice to know my answer was helpful.

Comment: In other words: instead of mailing me a beer you can just accept my answer as is common on SO ;)